# can not check updates on Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I receive the below shown error message when I try to update Android Studio despite the online mode is enabled

how to solve it

[image]

Comment: it says you do not have internet connection

Comment: @Mohit but i have internet connection

Answer (score 0):

If you already connect to Internet, you can try set a VPN or proxy，then check update again.